# Online web shop, instantiate all products

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm new to programming web sites (and so on the relationship between program and database) and I have encountered a problem.

I'm creating an online web shop that interacts and saves every info on a database.

The problem comes up regarding the shopping cart: I want that when a user adds a product in the cart, he can logout and when he logs in again he should find the cart unaltered, so I have a product as an object `Product` that has a `int productID` that is unique in the database.

I have a package DAO that interacts with the database, and there is this method:

```
/**
 * Queries the database in search of the shopping cart of the indicated user
 * @param userMail indicates the user from which take the shopping cart
 * @return the Shopping Cart of the user
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException if an error occurs with the connection to the database
 */
public static ShoppingCart getShoppingCartFromDatabase(String userMail) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    ShoppingCart updatedCart = new ShoppingCart(userMail);

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USERNAME, JDBC_PASSWORD)){

        try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM  " + TABLE_NAME + " "
                + "WHERE user = ?")) {
            pst.clearParameters();

            pst.setString(1, userMail);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String userMail = rs.getString("user");
                int IDProduct = rs.getInt("product");
                int npieces = rs.getInt("npieces");

                //HERE THE PROBLEM
                updatedCart.addToCart(IDProduct, npieces);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Errorin query: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error in connection: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return updatedCart;

}
```

The class `ShoppingCart`:

```
public class ShoppingCart {

    private final String userMail;
    private final List<ProductInCart> productsInCart;

    /**
     * Constructor of ShoppingCart.
     * It creates a new ProductInCart item and assigns it to the list of ShoppingCart
     * @param mail is the mail of the user, that is the owner of the shopping cart
     */
    public ShoppingCart(String mail){

        this.userMail = mail;
        this.productsInCart = new ArrayList<ProductInCart>();

    }

    //other methods, such as get and set etc

}
```

And the class `ProductInCart`:

```
public class ProductInCart{

    private final Product product;
    private int numberOfProducts;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     * @param product Product to be added
     * @param num Number of that item in the cart
     */
    public ProductInCart(Product product, int num){
        this.product = product;
        this.numberOfProducts = num;
    }

    //Other methods such as get and set, etc

}
```

The problem is that the method `public void addToCart(Product product, int num)` adds a product of type `Product` and I don't know how to get from the ID of the product to the product itself, other than creating again locally the product in `getShoppingCartFromDatabase` method.

And if there exists a solution, I want that when the server is shut down and starts again, it should be possible to query the database and restore the cart of the user.

EDIT

The `addToCart` method

```
/**
* Adds multiple items of a new product in the cart
* @param product added in cart
* @param num number of items of that product
* @throws ClassNotFoundException if an error occurs with the connection to the database
* @see ShoppingCartDAO#addOneItem(String, ProductInCart)
*/
public void addToCart(Product product, int num) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    ProductInCart added = new ProductInCart(product, num);
    this.productInCart.add(added);
    ShoppingCartDAO.addOneItem(this.userMail, added);
}
```

The method `ShoppingCartDAO.addOneItem(String, Product)` adds a row in the table of the `cart(IDProduct, IDUser, nPieces)` in the database, and `PK(IDProduct, IDUser)`.

Following the suggestions of the user thst, I add the solution I arrived to, even if I think it's not so optimal.

Premise: the products stored are of three types, `Product`, `ProfessionalProduct` and `ScholasticProduct`, both extend `Product`.

My solution is that in method `getShoppingCartFromDatabase(String userMail, User user)` I execute a query that queries the database (table `cart`) with the `userMail` (that is the ID of the user) and puts in a `ResultSet` all the products (or rather their IDs) and the number of items.

When I scan the `ResultSet`, I first clean the cart of the user, deleting the cart of that user in the database (I have a temporary copy in `ResultSet`), and then I add the product in the new cart and in the database: `updatedCart.addToCart(ProductDAO.getFromDatabase(productID), nPieces);`

That method now works because `ProductDAO.getFromDatabase(productID)` returns a `Product`.
The method `ProductDAO.getFromDatabase(productID)` executes a query on the database looking for the product with the indicated ID, then it returns a new object of type `Product` (or `ProfessionalProduct` or `ScholasticProduct` based on an `int productType` that discriminates between the types and allows me to call the right constructor).

My question is if there is a better solution, because mine seems a little bit complicated and prone to errors.

Comment: do you have an implementation of your update method?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking me, what update method?

Comment: do you already have a non-working implementation of your updatedCart.addToCart(IDProduct, npieces);
method

Comment: I have seen your edit, I suppose this is now rather a Code Review question. I would move your question there.

Comment: Please do not flag this and suggest that it be moved to Code Review. In the current form, it is not ready to be asked on Code Review. Please see [their How to Ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice. If you want to re-ask over there, following those guidelines, then please do so. However, I will not be migrating this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not clear if you are missing knowledge about relations in databases or if you are missing something in your datamodel, I try to show a solution to what I understood your problem is.

It would have been helpful, if you presented code where you show your attempt to solve the issue. This is usually a much better and faster approach.

As far as I understood your datamodel, you have a Product table using productId as primary key. Then there is a ShoppingCart table, that uses the email address of the customer as primary key.

Your problem is, that you do not understand, how to link products with the shopping cart. While you have understood, that the cart needs a reference to the products within, you do not realize that the shopping cart is actually not a single row, possibly not even a single table.

I would model it like this:

```
ShoppingCart
- ID            ====>  ShoppingCartItem
- owneremail           - shoppingCartID (FK relation to cart)
                       - productID (FK relation to products)
                       - amount (... add other item properties)
```

`FK` means Foreign Key.

When you store an item in the cart, you insert an item in the ShoppingCartItem table, referencing the cart over the shoppingCartID, this is the value of the ID column in the ShoppingCart table, where the email address matches the customers email.

So when you read a shopping cart from the database, you do:

```
SELECT ID 
  FROM ShoppingCart 
 WHERE email = <customer's email>
```

In your model, this should always return only one record. 
To retrieve the items, you call

```
SELECT productID,
       amount
  FROM ShoppingCartItem
 WHERE shoppingCartID = <ID from previous select>
```

To obtain additional product details, you need to join the product table over the productID:

```
SELECT i.productID,
       i.amount,
       p.name,
       p.price,
       p.description
  FROM ShoppingCartItem i join product p on p.ID = i.productID
 WHERE shoppingCartID = <ID from previous select>
```

To add items on purchase, you need the productID and the cart ID at hand to add the product to the cart. This seems already reflected in your code, but as you did not present the addToCart method, I cannot be sure.

```
INSERT INTO ShoppingCartItem (shoppingCartID, productID, amount)
     VALUES (<cart ID>, <productID>, <amount>)
```

Does this help you on your question?

Update:

You are asking for a more elegant way to handle all this. There are definitely some points you should improve on your current codebase.

- Use a `ConnectionPool`: Always fetching a connection from the DriverManager is very expensive. ConnectionPools keep connections open and ready to be fetched.
- Be specific on your statements: It is considered bad practice to do "select *" on a SQL query in your code. Always be specific and even better place alias names on your columns and use them in your resultset.getXXX() methods.
- Do not modify the database and expect the resultset to be your buffer. Create the cart object from the database and then persist it as a whole. The persistence can be transactional, so you delete in the same transaction as you create. This will make the operation safe from disruptions. If you don't, you have a gap in your code, when the cart is deleted, but the new cart is not yet saved. If you gag on a NPE or OOM or whatever at that moment, your cart is gone.
- Try to handle your objects as such in the DAO layer, do not move the database structure into your code too much. It is better to have a ShoppingCartDAO.saveCart(ShoppingCart) then having a items.add() paired with a ShoppingCartDAO.addItemToCart() method.
- In general: Do DB operations on objects, and do them in batches not too fine grained. This will cost you performance on the DB side and hinder you to refactor the object model without database changes. The object model is just one possible projection of your database model.

That's all I can add in the moment. You seem to be on a good track :-)

Comment: I understand what your solution is. I have designed the database, first with an ER diagram, then traslated it to relational database (I think it's called in this way in English). The problem is that the primary key of the cart, so the `ID` of the `ShoppingCart` in your example, it's a foreign key and refers to the userMail, because 1 cart=1 user. So it was a redundant information, because `Cart` ended up having a single column where it was saved as primary key the userMail (in foreign key).
Basically I think that my solution of the database is the same as yours, but without redundancy.

Comment: The redundancy is basically only redundancy as long as you do not set properties on the cart, like "when has it been created". To expire the cart later on. Not having this table now seems a benefit, but in the moment your cart grows into his own object you have potentially a larger refactoring to do.

Comment: It is a good solution, everytime a user wants to get the cart from the database, querying, instantiate every product that the user have in the cart, clearing the database relatively to the user's cart, and adding again the instantiated products? There is a better solution? It's to be said that a user can potentially have in a cart max 10 products, I think.

Comment: Ok I understand what you say, but I'm sure it (the cart) will not grow with informations.

Comment: When you just read the cart, there is no need to delete it, of course. Removing the cart from the database instead of synchronising the cart items with the database contents will not scale well. Deletion is a very expensive database operation. You should keep the current cart in memory, create an instance of the cart as stored in the database and then diff the objects and only apply the changes to the db.

Comment: Yeah understood, but the method addToCart automatically adds the product in the database, so if I don't clear the cart, I'll have two values with the same primary key

Comment: You cannot pick one and leave the other. My suggestion is, that delete-insert does not scale well. You should sync. My far more important point is, that you should separate object tree modification and database operations. You are currently mixing them.